# Raster file and vector file aren't matching

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, vector

I have opened a .tif file from WorldClim, specifically the bioclimatic variables. When I open them in QGIS, the raster file opens and looks normal; however, when I look at the extent of the raster I realise that the longitude ranges from (-180,540) and the latitude from (90, -270). Meanwhile, the vector layer I am using of the world has an extent that ranges from (-180,180), meaning that the two images do not match up, as shown in the image below:

[image]

I haven't used any reprojections or anything like that. Does anyone have any advice as to how to resolve this? Especially as when I look at the information of the two layers, they both have the same CRS and extent.

Vector layer information:

[image: Vector layer information]

Raster layer information:

[image: Raster layer information]

Comment: Please post your data.

Comment: the issue is with the current 30s resolution bioclim data from the worldclim data base here: https://www.worldclim.org/data/worldclim21.html .

Comment: however, it also happens with other data, such as the pnv_biome.type_biome00k.cold.deciduous.forest_p_1km_s0..0cm_2000..2017_v0.1.tif data file from the following website: https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/QQHCIK